# Source path missing in build definition Azure Devops

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a few webservices under the same team project folder in tfs called MyWebServices. For some reason some of the Webservices are not showing the full source mappings see picture the gray text below the name of the service.

How can I fix this for the webservices that don´t have it correctly set?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update your workspace mappings. `MyWebService2` is probably mapping `$/`.